# How to find max value of variable function with 2 constant parameters?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the maximum value of a function using `fminbnd`. I have used it with simple functions like `f(x) = x^2+2*x` so to find the minimum value I do `fminbnd(f,-10,10)`. To find the maximum value I just have to do `fminbnd(-f,-10,10)`.

Now I have another function with 3 variables but I want 2 of them to be constant:

```
f(Q,m,Fx) = (Fx^2*(m-1))/sqrt( (m*Fx^2-1)^2 + (Fx^2*(Fx^2-1)^2*(m-1)^2*Q^2) )
```

I'm currently plotting it using `ezplot(f(q,m,Fx), [0 8 0 3])` being `q` and `m` constant values. If a try to get the maximum value with `fminbnd(-f(q,m,Fx),0,8)` it gives me an error.

How can I find the maximum value of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function as function-handle and then use an anonymous function in the call for `ezplot` and `fminbnd`. This reduces your problem to only one variable, so it can be handled appropriately and generates no errors.

```
% define function-handle
f = @(Q,m,Fx) (Fx^2*(m-1))/sqrt( (m*Fx^2-1)^2 + (Fx^2*(Fx^2-1)^2*(m-1)^2*Q^2) );

% define constants
q = 1;
m = 10;

% plot the curve
ezplot(@(Fx) f(q,m,Fx), [0 8 0 3])

% compute the maximum
Fx = fminbnd(@(Fx) -f(q,m,Fx),0,8)
Fy = f(q,m,Fx)

% plot the maximum as point
hold on
plot(Fx,Fy,'*')
axis([0 8 0 1.2])
```

Gives the following result:

[image: result]